# How can I make IsMouseOver not care about other things covering up the control?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, ismouseover

I use the `IsMouseOver` property frequently in my WPF program. Unfortunately, I have other visual elements from other branches of the visual tree that sometimes cover up my controls. When they cover up my controls, the `IsMouseOver` becomes false on my controls, even when my mouse is over the covered up control.

How can my control have a property like `IsMouseOver` that doesn't care if it's covered up at the cursor location? Like a hit test that can tunnel threw covers.

I looked at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259161/can-i-make-wpf-set-ismouseover-for-both-the-covering-and-covered-element) but I don't think I can use it, because it basically uses polling every time that the mouse moves. I think that would slow down my program significantly, because my visual tree is extensive.

Note that the visual elements that cover up my controls are not children of my controls.

**Edit:** Setting `IsHitTestVisible` to false on the element that is doing the covering would be a very nice solution, but when I do that then the covering element doesn't interact with the mouse at all. I need both the covered and the covering elements to react to the mouse.

Comment: Are the "other things" covering the control supposed to care about the mouse?

Comment: If there is somthing covering the control the mouse can't be over the control because its over the other control.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Metaphor: My cell phone is sitting on my desk. Therefore, my phone is over both my desk and the floor.

Comment: Think of the mouse as your eyes, you can't see the desk though the phone and you can't see the floor through the desk, It sounds like you need to think of something else other than IsMouseOver events, only one thing can be directly under the mouse at one time

Comment: I probably do need to use something other than `IsMouseOver` events. I want to use something similar though. Many of my controls should change their appearance when the mouse hovers over them. Unfortunately things like large transparent overlays and doted-line selection adorners cover up part of my controls sometimes. When the mouse hovers over these things, the `IsMouseOver` goes false and the underlying control changes to look as though the mouse is not hovering over it. It looks bad and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Make the covering control invisible to [Hit Testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx) by setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"`

```
<Grid>
  <Control1/>

  <!-- Control2 will visually "cover" Control1, but mouse events will "pass thru" To Control1 -->
  <Control2 IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That is a great solution for the question I originally wrote. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I have edited my original question to include a description of why I don't think it works for me.